# Help interpreting an interaction term from R output of linear regression

Tags: r, modeling, interaction, interpretation

So I am familiar with the concept interaction. However in most instances that I have come across, a significant interaction term is in the same direction as the 2 individual terms. However I have come across a somewhat cancelling out effect and was wondering what someone with a little more data analytics experience makes of it.

[image]

Apologies I can't add more but I don't own the data.
The top most term is the intercept. The second term is something that must be controlled for and so you can ignore this.

The third term is a fairly fundamental term that doesn't change. Perhaps you can think of this as gender?
The fourth term is less fundamental, that may well change. Perhaps you can think of this as a treatment group?
The last term is the interaction between the third and fourth terms, i.e. there are 2 binary variables at play.

Because the interaction term is in the opposite direction, should I interpret this as cancelling out the "treatment group" variable (-0.67)? Or does it cancel out both? The standard error is fairly large so I feel I could go either way.

Should I rely on my background knowledge of the system at play to answer this?

Any and all feedback would be welcome, even if it's, "you need to tell us what the data is representing".

Comment: Apparently, the mathematical or statistical model must be specified in order to assess the interaction effect. I  do not understand which sign can be assigned to variables individually ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar The model is just data ~ A + B + A:B or data ~ A*B.

Comment: Plot the group means. Then calculate them manually with the coefficients. That should help you understand this. Considering uncertainties is then an additional step.

Comment: @Roland The group means will be the same as the model, surely?

Comment: A model is a model, group means are group means. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: your data or variables are binary. Is it justified  to define interaction in multiplicative terms without assigning the probabilities?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I have no idea. Perhaps? The samples are fairly even and the 2 variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: Stuart, I hate to say this, and meaning nothing personal by it, but you will be better off ignoring all comments posted here by @Subhash.  As far as your question goes, could you clarify what "same direction" might mean?  Please note that since an interaction is a *nonlinear* function of the variables, the sign of the coefficient has no ready interpretation and cannot be compared to anything else.  Roland has given you good advice: two binary variables have only four possible combined values, thereby determining four groups, and your model is equivalent to fitting a mean to each group.

Comment: thanks @whuber To rephrase my question, can I ignore the effects of the "treatment" variable when the "gender" variable is active? Obviously it must be part of the model because there is an interaction but can I assume that when I need to account for the third term down (gender) I can ignore the fourth (treatment) and the fifth (the interaction) since the means are so close? Is this a fair interpretation?

Comment: You probably shouldn't ignore significant effects.  But to help you out conceptually, here's a proposal: if you were to recode the two binary variables (treatment and gender) by swapping the roles of $0$ and $1$, that would (a) negate their coefficients but (b) leave the interaction term the same.  The result would then consist of all positive coefficients.  If that would make you happy, then you're done.

Comment: @whuber I'm fairly sure that if I were to swap out the terms as you say then everything would be negated, no?

Comment: @whuber I think I see now what you were saying. If I reflect one of them then I get an insignicant term falling out and then the interpretation is clear. Many thanks. If you want to offer that as an answer then I'll out it as correct.